# What does "take out your book" mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs, phrasal-verbs

What does this phrase mean? "take out your book"

Because I have found no relevant meaning of take+out as a phrasal verb in the online dictionaries. Can any one help me?

Comment: What is the context? You can take a book out of the library, which means to borrow it. You can take a book out of a classroom desk.

Answer (score 3):

"take out your book" means "take your book out of the container it is currently in".

In a classroom, at the beginning of a class a teacher might say "Take out your grammar book" , omitting, but implying, that you are to take it out from where it currently is, perhaps in your desk or your satchel.  It could be used in similar circumstances too.

It's both grammatically acceptable and, in context, easily understandable.